# Function to update href in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, href

I make web resume. I'd like to add URL's to my projects and employers.
I tried this function but it didn't work (only first project updates and takes the value of URL from last element in projects array).

`for (project in projects.projects) {
    document.getElementById("ptitle").href=projects.projects[project].url/  }`

My code is here: http://bl.ocks.org/DariaAlekseeva/c58df25c4cded4d1a678

Thank you!

Comment: you can only have one object per ID.

Comment: What is the / at the end there?  You want ; first off.

Comment: Looks like you are overwriting  the href as you loop leaving you with the last value to be in the loop. I haven't clicked the link, you should post the relevant source code here with your question. To check your loop is looping add `console.log(projects.projects[project].url);` and open your browser console to view the output.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be a single element on the page with a given ID. `document.getElementById()` will always only find the first instance of an element with the given ID.

The code you've shown in your post would loop over the array of objects resetting the the same element's `href` to a new value each time.

Consider using [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) when working with more than one element that need to be represented in a similar way.

Here's an example that assumes the length of your HTML class set matches your array of objects, and that they're both in the order you expect. Should steer you in the right direction.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2v25zeLu/)

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="myClass"></li>
  <li class="myClass"></li>
  <li class="myClass"></li>
  <li class="myClass"></li>
  <li class="myClass"></li>
  <li class="myClass"></li>
</ul>
```

JS (using jQuery, since you seem to be using it about half the time anyway.)

```
var projects = { 'projects' : 
  [
    {'url' : 'zero'},
    {'url' : 'one'},
    {'url' : 'two'},
    {'url' : 'three'},
    {'url' : 'four'},
    {'url' : 'five'}
  ]
};
    
$('.myClass').each(function (index) {
  $(this).text(projects.projects[index].url);
});
```